# A question about bremsstrahlung radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gravitational-waves

It’s gravitational radiation, a sphere of mass expanding in a symmetrical manner will not give off gravitational waves.

Does it work the same way with electromagnetism, will this result in an expanding sphere of charges particles not producing any electromagnetic waves even if they are accelerating while doing so?

Comment: Charge particles.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung): “Bremsstrahlung is electromagnetic radiation produced by the deceleration of a charged particle when deflected by another charged particle.” This doesn’t seem to describe what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

No, a charged sphere expanding and contracting symmetrically doesn't give off EM radiation. You can use gauss' law to compute the electric field and you will always find that the field outside the sphere is just given by coulomb's law.

Comment: You're assuming that the sphere has uniform charge. But the question refers to "particles", so uniformity can only be an approximation.

Comment: @JohnDoty I think this answer is making a pretty reasonably assumption given the lack of details (and prevalence of typos) in the question.